# Koin: Workaround for Single(override = true) {}

Tags: kotlin, koin

When migrating from Koin 3.0.2 to 3.1 we noticed that we can't do anymore

```
loadKoinModules(module { single(override = true) { serviceMock } })
```

What is the workaround for this in the new version now that the "override" argument has been removed?

Answer (score 1):

Since Koin 3.1 override is the default. The last module with the same mapping will override the previous.

```kotlin
val myModuleA = module {
    single<Service> { ServiceImp() }
}
val myModuleB = module {
    single<Service> { TestServiceImp() }
}

startKoin {
    // TestServiceImp will override ServiceImp definition
    modules(myModuleA,myModuleB)
}
```

Here's the [documentation](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-core/modules/#overriding-definition-or-module-310)